# Custom Fields in get response body object

Tags: java, rest, get, jersey, jax-rs

How to make custom fields that displays in get response body by sending fields in request header like this GET: 
api/v1/custom-fields?fields=name,city,state

That means I should display name, city, state values only in get response not all fields from response object.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is **SelectableEntityFilteringFeature**. After registering this feature, In the request object you can select the fields that you want to display.

So in you're case the request URL would say `select` certain fields.

`api/v1/custom-fields?select=name,city,state`

And in the return object, only values of "name,city,state" will be returned and not the whole object.

Refer to the example provided [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html#ef.selectable.annotations).